# F# : list.[(argument)..] errors in Match Pattern

Tags: list, indexing, f#, match

I have created a function where i want to match the length of a list from a given index to the end of the list. example. list.[4..] will give you a new list with the elements from list from index 4 to the end. I know this is true since i have done this lots of times.

But now when i try to do this in a match pattern then it errors:

"Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

my code looks like this:

```
 let rec possibilityGuess n p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS   =
  match (List.length (SS.[n..])) with 
  |1 -> match (validate (List.item(0) SS) (List.item(n) SS)) with
        |(0,0) -> [(p1+1);p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(0,1) -> [p1;(p2+1);p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(0,2) -> [p1;p2;(p3+1);p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(0,3) -> [p1;p2;p3;(p4+1);p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(0,4) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;(p5+1);p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(1,0) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;(p6+1);p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(1,1) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;(p7+1);p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(1,2) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;(p8+1);p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(1,3) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;(p9+1);p10;p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(2,1) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;(p10+1);p11;p12;p13;p14]
        |(2,2) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;(p11+1);p12;p13;p14]
        |(3,0) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;(p12+1);p13;p14]
        |(3,1) -> [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;(p13+1);p14]
        |_ ->     [p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12;p13;(p14+1)]
  |_ -> match (validate (List.item(0) SS) (List.item(n) SS)) with
        |(0,0) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) (p1+1) p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(0,1) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 (p2+1) p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(0,2) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 (p3+1) p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(0,3) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 (p4+1) p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(0,4) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 (p5+1) p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(1,0) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 (p6+1) p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(1,1) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 (p7+1) p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(1,2) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 (p8+1) p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(1,3) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 (p9+1) p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(2,1) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 (p10+1) p11 p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(2,2) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 (p11+1) p12 p13 p14 SS)
        |(3,0) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 (p12+1) p13 p14 SS)
        |(3,1) -> (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 (p13+1) p14 SS)
        |_ ->     (possibilityGuess (n+1) p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 (p14+1) SS)
printfn "%A" (possibilityGuess 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 S)
```

so it is in the second line where i try to match `List.length SS.[n..] with`1` thats the problem which i cant understand why?

n is an int that starts in 0 and adds 1 for each recursive call.

I have tried reaarranging it so i would match `1` with `x when x = List.length SS.[n..]` this gives the same error.

So as i understand it then it wont accept the `SS.[n..]` in a match pattern which really confuses me since i know this expression will work in other cases.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're doing `SS.[n..]` in a `match` is not the issue; the real problem (as indicated directly by the error message) is that at the point you do `SS.[n..]`, the type of `SS` is not known. The fact that you pass the result of that expression to `List.length` doesn't help because *any* type that supports slicing *could* return a list. Give `SS` an explicit type annotation and all is well:

```
let rec possibilityGuess n p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 (SS:list<_>) =
   ...
```